# fetch the value from any one of dropdown list from two dropdown list

Tags: java, struts, taglib

I have two dropdown lists to select value from. What I want is that when the user selects a value from the any one of the list, he cannot select a  value from the another list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some more details about your problem and what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to the selected item change event from both lists and when one of them is triggered then disable the other list. This assumes both lists are in the same context (class or form). 
The problem with this is that if the person made a mistake he is now not capable of changing his selection in the previous list. You may need either a reset or a "none" item in each list that when selected will enable the other list again. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

On selection of any dropdown onchange call a function and pass the

```
disableDrop(id of other dropdown);

disableDrop(id) {

$("#" + id option[value]").prop('disabled',true);

}
```